# Discriminate between User Groups using User ID in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am working on a pre-existing Google Analytics set up and having to develop an understanding of how certain users of our website are interacting with the site.

An important component of this will require user-journey analysis to understand how, say, a premium user interacts with the site compared to a free user compared to someone who isn't logged in at all.

I understand that I can start using User-ID to start discriminating between logged in users and those who are not; however, I am unsure of how to handle the distinction between free and premium users.

Is there any way to add additional information to User-ID to include a "User Group"? Or is there an alternative recommended way to create these segments in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is certainly possible to pass something along with the User-ID to identify the premium and the free users. Example: P-007 vs F-006. I'd recommend you to look into [Custom Dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)(CD) instead.

I'd set up a **User Scoped** CD and along with your sign-in event push the string "free" or "premium" along with it.

Reason for doing this is that when you set the User-ID, the user is identified by it across multiple devices. If a user starts with free, F-007 and then later converts to premium, P-007, then the user suddenly becomes a different user to GA. Using a CD will allow you to keep the ID the same while converting the user to "free" or "premium" without losing the client.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much for the recommendation.